# Javascript Menu Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

New to coding, please help me out. I have a sliding code for a vertical nav. When the user hovers over the nav, it slides out to the right. I want it to stay active once the user clicks on the nav. How do I go about doing that? Here is a link to a visiual

http://edgecastcdn.net/00009B//TEMP/NAV/index.html

in return for you help, here is a joke you guys might enjoy (if you haven't heard of it already)

> A wife asks her husband, a computer programmer; "Could you please go
>   to the store for me and buy one carton of milk, and if they have eggs,
>   get 6!"
>
> A short time later the husband comes back with 6 cartons of milk.
>
> The wife asks him, "Why the hell did you buy 6 cartons of milk?"
>
> He replied, "They had eggs."

Thanks guys, any help is appreciated! Here is the code. Let me know if you need the css too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    slide("#sliding-navigation", 30, 15, 150, .8);
});

function slide(navigation_id, pad_out, pad_in, time, multiplier){
// creates the target paths
var list_elements = navigation_id + " li.sliding-element";
var link_elements = list_elements + " a";

// initiates the timer used for the sliding animation
var timer = 0;

// creates the slide animation for all list elements 
$(list_elements).each(function(i)
{
    // margin left = - ([width of element] + [total vertical padding of element])
    $(this).css("margin-left","-180px");
    // updates timer
    timer = (timer*multiplier + time);
    $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "0" }, timer);
    $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "12px" }, timer);
    $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "0" }, timer);
});

// creates the hover-slide effect for all link elements         
$(link_elements).each(function(i)
{
    $(this).hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_out }, 150);
    },      
    function()
    {
        $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_in }, 150);
    });

});

}
```

Here is my CSS code (Updated with Douglas "active" code) Thanks!

```
body 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #1d1d1d;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
}

h2  
{ 
color: #999;
margin-bottom: 0; 
margin-left:13px;
background:url(navigation.jpg) no-repeat;
height:40px;
}

h2 span
{
display: none;
}

p   navigation-block
{ 
color: #00b7e6; 
margin-top: .5em;
font-size: .75em;
padding-left:15px;  
}

#navigation-block {
position:relative;
}

#hide {
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:-190px;
}

ul#sliding-navigation
{
list-style: none;
font-size: 0.75em;
margin: 30px 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element h3,
ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a
{
display: block;
width: 150px;
padding: 2px 18px;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element h3
{
color: #fff;
background:#333333 url(heading_bg.jpg) repeat-y;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a
{
color: #999;
background:#222 url(tab_bg.jpg) repeat-y;
border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a.selected { color: #cc0000; }
{
color: #FFF;
margin-top: 0.5em;
font-size: 10pt;
padding-left:15px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a:hover { color: #00b7e6; background:#2a2a2a; }
#navigation-block p {
color: #FFF;
margin-top: 0.5em;
font-size: 10pt;
padding-left:15px;
font-weight: bolder;
}


.active{
  padding-left:12px;
  /*Add whatever other styles you need */
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "once the user clicks on the nav"? Do you mean the main level nav, or the slided-out nav, or after the new page loads?

Comment: A Bit confusing, could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example?  Even if it doesn't work right, then it will be a bit easier to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: not sure what a jsfiddle is, sorry. So when the user hovers over a link, then clicks on it, it should stay active. Here is a visual

http://edgecastcdn.net/00009B//TEMP/NAV/index.html

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: SpYk3HH has a link to jsFiddle in his comment... Pretty self explanatory, it's a place to put working code examples to show others and demonstrate issues you're having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your nav doesn't actually change the page, just loads (or switches out) new content on the page.

The easiest way to make this stay after a user clicks a link would be to add a class with the correct settings. For example:

jQuery

```
$(link_elements).hover(
  function()
  {
    $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_out }, 150);
  },      
  function()
  {
    $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_in }, 150);
  }
).click(function(){
  $(link_elements).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

CSS

```
.active{
  padding-left:12px;
  /*Add whatever other styles you need */
}
```

EDIT: Added CSS

---

EDIT:
Okay, I see what I missed before - the jQuery is setting the padding inline which overrides the external CSS. You technically could use `!important` in the `.active` CSS, but I personally like this method more.

Basically, I add the `active` class like before, but I only use it as a reference. When a user clicks a link, the `active` class is added. If a link has the `active` class, it does not animate on mouseout. When a not `active` class is clicked, `active` is removed from all other nav links, they're all animated to their start point, and the new link is made `active`.

This may be better explained with the relevant code:

```
// creates the hover-slide effect for all link elements         
$(link_elements).each(function(i) {
    $(this)
        .hover(
            function() {
                $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_out }, 150);
            }, function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass("active"))
                    $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_in }, 150);
            })
        .click(
            function() {
                $(link_elements).not($(this)).removeClass("active").animate({ paddingLeft: pad_in}, 150);
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
}); // End `each` loop
```

And the related jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eAaCn/
(added `console.log()` and `return false` in the jsFiddle for testing only)

Comment: Did you add CSS for the `active` class?

Comment: I really appreciate your help Douglas, but I can' get it to work. I have added the css and it's still not functioning properly :( let me post my css code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hopefully my edit fixes the issue. Technically, the way I said at first will work, but you'd need to add `!important` after the padding statement. Anyways, the now above described works nicer.

Comment: Wow! Amazing Douglas! Thank you soooooo much for you help! You're a life saver :) and thank you for the explanation as well!

Comment: Hey Douglas, thank you so much for all your help. I just got 1 more quick question. If I wanted to call in some styles from the css when the button is active. How do I go about doing that? Thank you in advance buddy

Comment: After the button is clicked, it has the `active` class added. Use the `.active` reference in your CSS and style it however you see fit. Also, feel free to change "active" to whatever class name you prefer - won't make a difference. You're welcome :)

Comment: I've included the .active class elements in the css but it's not getting called. Am I missing something? can you check the jsFiddle real quick? http://jsfiddle.net/eAaCn/2/ thanks again Douglas!

Comment: This goes to CSS priorities. In short, more specifically located styles will override less specific one. when the CSS reference is of equal location specificity, the last one read will be used (the one towards the bottom of the sheet). This is definitely worth researching more if you work with CSS even semi often.

Comment: TL,DR: Use `ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element .active{` instead of `.active{`.

Comment: YESSSS!!! :) A thousand thank yous Mr. Crosby!!! Sending some karma your way lol. Thank you for all your help! :) Have an excellent day! :)